# Match-3 Shuffle Required?

Tags: algorithm, software-engineering, procedural-generation

How can I detect if there are no more potential matches possible and therefore a shuffle is required?

Comment: What have you tried? Questions should show some effort towards researching a solution.

Comment: The most naive solution is clearly to apply your "match" logic to every node, individually. If the function that checks for a "match" returns false for every possible node, then you are out of matches.

Answer (score 1):

You can always just do a naive approach.  Just iterate through all pieces and see if there's a match in any direction, and if you get to the end before any matches are detected, then you have no matches.